# Different result between SELECT and UPDATE using same WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running a select that brings me zero results:

```
select EVCON.DTATUA, EVCON.QTESTQ, EVCON.QTRESV
from int1160 evcon     
WHERE EVCON.CDEMKP = 24                          
     --AND EVCON.QTESTQ <> 4
     AND ESTOQUE_MP(24,EVCON.CDARTI,EVCON.TMARTI, 'N') <> 4
     AND EXISTS (                                
                 SELECT 1 FROM APC1060 ARTI      
                 WHERE   ARTI.CDARTI=EVCON.CDARTI
                     AND ARTI.TMARTI=EVCON.TMARTI
                     AND ARTI.CDSKUP  = '609176268536'
                 );
```

But when I change to update, "one row updated" is shown:

```
 UPDATE INT1160 EVCON                            
 SET EVCON.DTATUA = SYSDATE,                     
     EVCON.QTESTQ = 4,                           
     EVCON.QTRESV = 0
--select EVCON.DTATUA, EVCON.QTESTQ, EVCON.QTRESV
 --from int1160 evcon     
 WHERE EVCON.CDEMKP = 24                          
     --AND EVCON.QTESTQ <> 4
     AND ESTOQUE_MP(24,EVCON.CDARTI,EVCON.TMARTI, 'N') <> 4
     AND EXISTS (                                
                 SELECT 1 FROM APC1060 ARTI      
                 WHERE   ARTI.CDARTI=EVCON.CDARTI
                     AND ARTI.TMARTI=EVCON.TMARTI
                     AND ARTI.CDSKUP  = '609176268536'
                 );
```

Function ESTOQUE_MP just do selects, not updates, etc

Whats wrong with that clausule?

Comment: What happens if you knock up an anonymous PL/SQL block that does the update and returns the primary key into a variable that you then output via dbms_output? That should give you some clues, hopefully.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that `ESTOQUE_MP(24,EVCON.CDARTI,EVCON.TMARTI, 'N') <> 4` always returns the same results?